# ServiceStack Accessing Session Directly

Tags: session, servicestack

I'm having trouble getting direct manipulation of sessions working properly.

Using some code from the source and a tip from Demis, I've put together something in our unit test client to auth the user and then recover the session.

The AuthResponse I'm getting from the service has a SessionId of 533, which results in a constructed urn of "urn:iauthsession:533", whereas the urn in the Redis cache is "urn:iauthsession:sbQBLwb1WpRj8DqQ7EdL", so obviously, the thing being passed to the urn builder in the running code is not simply the session id (or the overload being used is not what I think it is).

Here's the code we're using in our test base class to try to recover the session from the auth call:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(ServiceTestAppHost.BaseUrl)
    {
        UserName = userName,
        Password = password,
        AlwaysSendBasicAuthHeader = true
    };

var response = client.Post<AuthResponse>("/auth/basic", new Auth() { UserName = userName, Password = password, RememberMe = true });

var sessionKey = IdUtils.CreateUrn<IAuthSession>(response.SessionId);

var session = _appHost.TryResolve<ICacheClient>().Get<SsoUserSession>(sessionKey);﻿
```

Any idea why the constructed urn is not matching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should now be [fixed with this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/b8ea8d8ea2a848acd5557644256cbc70e9be76e9) which is available in v4.0.22 that's [now available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Is this bug present in 3.9.71 as well? And could it cause a bizarre issue where the Service extension method GetSession() seems to be (occasionally) returning the wrong session?